# Express.js: how to get deeper in Mongo database to get an array from it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I've got problem with getting array from my DB. I'm sharing a picture of how it looks in this post. [mongo db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/airuS.png)

I'd like to access "messages" array but I don't know how to. The code I use to get data from db:

```js
app.get("/getMessages", (req, res) => {
  UserModel.find({ name: "Pablo"  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});
```

It returns whole user. I tried with res.json(result.messages) but it didn't work (returns error). In react I tried  the code below, but no luck.

```js
const [listOfMessages, setListOfMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getMessages").then((response) => {
      setListOfMessages(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container className="p-0 h-100">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sender name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Message</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {listOfMessages.map((message) => {
            return (
              <tr key={message._id}>
                <td>{message.messages.sender}</td>
                <td>{message.messages.title}</td>
                <td>{message.messages.message}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Container>
  );
```

Comment: Can you show the schema you are using for the User model?

Comment: Is this using Mongoose? Also, what is the error that it returns when you try `result.messages`? Perhaps `findOne()` is what you are looking for here instead?

Comment: In your Axios result, wouldn't it just be `response.data.messages`?

Comment: @jjroley that's the schema const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  messages: [
    {
      sender: { type: String },
      tile: { type: String },
      message: { type: String },
    },
  ],
});

const UserModel = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
module.exports = UserModel;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now it works. THX @jjroley and @user20042973 for helping. I had typo in schema which I fixed. Also result.messages works with findOne(). Thanks.